# Make last image in galary Base, Small and Thumbnail query - Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3, image, query, magento2.3.5

The following sql query changes the Base, Small and Thumbnail to the first image.

We want to use something like this query, but then select the last image in position and make that Base, Small and Thumbnail, not the first. Because the last image position value is for every product different and dynamic, how can we achieve this?

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
AND mgv.entity_id = ev.entity_id
AND ev.attribute_id IN (87, 88, 89)
AND mgv.position = 1;
```

Comment: https://www.siphor.com/adding-and-removing-media-images-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Comment: @Chiku, Thanks, but that is not what we are looking for. This removes all images. We do not want to change any image, only the selection of the base, small and thumbnail.